# How to make progress bar running on for loop

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-volley, android-progressbar, android-database

I have this method to get data from server using volley and store it into sqlite database using ormlite. I'm doing this on splash screen. so now I want to show some progressbar when this process happen, the progress bar already appear and now I want to set the progress of progress bar inside the for loop. But I dont know why my progress bar keep on 0% until the process finish. when I look at the log the progress keep update but maybe because it inside a loop the progress not appear. How can I make the progress appear in my progressdialog?? below is my code

```
 private void fetchMOffice() {
            mOfficeAdapter = new TableMOfficeAdapter(this);
            List<TableMOffice> listOffice = mOfficeAdapter.getAllDatabyLup();

        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("Downloading File...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        showDialog();

        for (int i=0; i<listOffice.size(); i++) {
            TableMOffice item = listOffice.get(i);
            lupMOffice = item.getLup();
            //  locationIdArray.add(item.getKode_office());
            break;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "lup fetchMOffice: " +lupMOffice );

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                ConnectionManager.MASTER_M_OFFICE, new Response.Listener<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);



                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    dbAdapter = new TableMOfficeAdapter(SplashScreenActivity.this);
                    //  dbAdapter.deleteAll();
                    //   SQLiteStatement insert = mDb.compileStatement(sql);

                    // check for error flag
                    if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                        jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("m_office");



                        for ( i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject versionObj = null;

                                versionObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                                int id = versionObj.getInt("id");
                                String office = versionObj.getString("office");
                                String kode_office = versionObj.getString("kode_office");
                                String channel = versionObj.getString("channel");
                                String jenis = versionObj.getString("jenis");
                                String alamat = versionObj.getString("alamat");
                                String kota = versionObj.getString("kota");
                                String propinsi = versionObj.getString("propinsi");
                                String pic = versionObj.getString("pic");
                                String pic_phone = versionObj.getString("pic_phone");
                                String map_lat = versionObj.getString("map_lat");
                                String map_lng = versionObj.getString("map_lng");
                                String upd = versionObj.getString("upd");
                                String lup = versionObj.getString("lup");
                                String ket = versionObj.getString("ket");
                                String region = versionObj.getString("region");
                                String rek = versionObj.getString("rek");
                                String bank = versionObj.getString("bank");
                                String rental = versionObj.getString("rental");
                                Log.e("isitabeloffice",   Integer.toString(id));
                                ctx = getApplicationContext();
                                dbAdapter.delete(SplashScreenActivity.this,id);
                                //dbAdapter.delete(ctx,id);
                                dbAdapter.insertData(new TableMOffice(), id, office, kode_office, channel,
                                        jenis, alamat, kota, propinsi, pic, pic_phone, map_lat, map_lng,
                                        upd, lup, ket, region, rek, bank, rental);

                                progress = (i+1)*100/jsonArray.length();
                                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                                }

                    } else {

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    //Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                hideDialog();
                //Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();


                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }
```

Comment: you are not running on a ui thread so the progressbar wont update. Did you thought about implementing an AsyncTask?

Comment: yeah I know if using asynctask it can do that, but I want to ask if it is possible using volley for case like this? how to make it run on ui thread? or maybe can we use handler to delay the for loop?